# Exclude first factor from intercept in R

Tags: r, regression

I'm doing a multi-variable regression in `R`, where one variable is set as a factor. If I do the regression, the intercept is set to the first factor and all following factors are set relative to that.
So if I do the following regression:

```
pe1n = lm(return_1_yr_abs~size+fe_year+retained_binary,data=rtn_1_yr)
```

I get following output:

```
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)      17.516160  15.031941   1.165   0.2457
size             -0.001619   0.001214  -1.333   0.1845
fe_year2         -3.532222  16.954761  -0.208   0.8352  
fe_year3          6.759767  16.303710   0.415   0.6790  
fe_year4        -73.769141  39.464482  -1.869   0.0635 .
fe_year6        -27.113332  24.232382  -1.119   0.2649  
fe_year7        -17.705589  26.214533  -0.675   0.5004  
fe_year8        -12.726297  28.849918  -0.441   0.6597  
fe_year9          1.832507  15.557559   0.118   0.9064  
fe_year10         5.282221  12.871480   0.410   0.6821  
fe_year11        13.584084  16.376386   0.829   0.4081  
retained_binary  -6.457557  12.922218  -0.500   0.6180
```

`R` takes the first year as intercept and now sets all other variables in relation to it. What I want to do is have the average return across all variables as intercept incl. statistical values. And all other variables should be set in relation to that. I already searched after a few solutions and tried them out, but nothing gives me my desired results:

- change contrasts to sum instead treatment -> last year is missing since contrasts are one less than variables
- offset intercept by the mean and have no intercept -> no statistical output regarding the mean
- set intercept manually to mean -> no statistical output

The final result I'm looking for would look like this:

```
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)       11.70148    X          X       X
size              X           X          X       X
fe_year1          5.81468     X          X       X
fe_year2          2.27679     X          X       X
```

and so on, with every year until 11 included.

I hope the question is clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: Better formatting is `pe1n = lm(return_1_yr_abs ~ size + fe_year + retained_binary, data=rtn_1_yr)`

Comment: Edited it, thanks!

Comment: Your desired result may not be possible through an `lm()` call as at least one group in a categorical variable must be dropped (n-1) else you face perfect collinearity. You can possibly create a *fe_year1* variable calculated during post-estimation.

Comment: share you data please